# Is kangaroo meat safe to eat raw such as kangaroo tartare?

Tags: food-safety, raw-meat, tartare, kangaroo

I know that kangaroo meat is usually cooked rare because it's so low in fat.

I also know that certain meats are not safe unless well cooked, such as chicken and pork.

But what about kangaroo? For me it's the most delicious red meat so if I like steak tartare I know I should like kangaroo tartare, but how could I make sure that I'm doing it the safest way possible, if there is a safe way?

Comment: Where does your kangaroo meat come from? If it was a wild kangaroo, the risk for parasite infestation is probably higher than with a farmed kangaroo.

Comment: Are these "free range roos"?

Comment: It would be from either a butcher shop or a supermarket, but I don't think we farm kangaroos though I'm naive of what the supply chain actually is (and I'm travelling overseas right now so can't ask so easily).

Comment: The links in the highest voted answer appear dead / changed, but Macro Meats is the most common brand I've seen in supermarkets and their page confirms they are not farmed http://www.macromeats-gourmetgame.com.au/Aboutus/KangarooIndustry.aspx#.U2zanLHNkgo

Answer (score 16):

It seems the meat is not farmed at all but entirely "harvested" in the wild
http://www.daff.gov.au/agriculture-food/meat-wool-dairy/ilg/industries/kangaroos. 
So it should be treated as a game meat rather than a farmed one - i.e. best to cook it.

Here's advice from the Department of Primary Industries saying you should never feed raw kangaroo to your dog, so I'd err on the side of caution
http://new.dpi.vic.gov.au/pets/pests-and-diseases/health-care

Comment: The advice re: feeding it to dogs doesn't really apply here - there are things that dogs shouldn't eat (chocolate, for example) that humans can eat (and enjoy) :)

Comment: That is true—but in the second page kjm submitted it states that "raw meat/offal (especially kangaroo or deer) can be full of parasites. Feeding of these raw meats and offal to dogs can pass on diseases like Toxoplasmosis or Hydatids to humans on the farm." Toxoplasmosis can also be spread through raw or undercooked meat consumption and may cause flu-like symptoms and complications in pregnancy. I, too, would err on the side of caution.

Comment: @AshleyNunn: It's true that some substances that are fine for humans are toxic to cats and dogs, but those are very specific and whether or not it's *cooked* doesn't normally make any difference. In fact they generally have very little trouble with raw meat; so if there's a type of meat that you wouldn't want to feed raw to your pet, you definitely won't want to eat it raw yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Kangaroo meat is recognised as a health risk - as it's a bush meat, and is butchered in field. It can take up to two weeks before it is transported to a processor where the testing regime (which itself is only sampling a small number of carcasses) is only for salmonella and e.coli - not for the many many other pathogens and diseases kangaroos carry. There is good reason that farmed livestock are wormed, drenched and husbanded.

I really wouldn't go near it, and you most certainly should not eat it undercooked which is a recognised health risk. See [this article on contamination from my site.](http://www.kangaroosatrisk.org/contamination.html)

Comment: Welcome! I've edited your answer, because we require that any sort of self-promotion (including linking to your own site) come with disclosure. Without that, it may be flagged and deleted. See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/referencing for details. (@JanDoggen I assume you just didn't notice, so no worries, but when you're editing links to not show the url you probably want to watch out for ones that are the user's own site, since it gets harder to notice post-edit.)

Comment: @Cascabel Sure. I did not notice the name of the answer author

Answer (score 4):

While you question is not a duplicate, most of the answer for [How safe is steak tartare?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4388/how-safe-is-steak-tartare) applies here.

If you have good quality meat, from a reputable provider, you are likely to be fine.

Given that you would likely need to find a good butcher, I would suggest you talk to him/her and ask if they would eat their product in that way.  If not, perhaps take their advice.

Answer (score 0):

Kangaroo meat is subject to the same level of inspection as microbial testing as other red meats. It is perfectly safe to eat in the same way as all other red meats.  There are no parasite problems in the product.  The only proviso is one which applies equally to lamb or beef: that pregnant women, the elderly, very young children and sick people should not eat any raw meat due to possible toxoplasmosis rick.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a really old post, however id like to add something to the conversation.
6 days ago I went to a fancy restaurant and ate Kangaroo meat, it was quite raw, as you would eat if it was raw beef.
From the night i ate this kanagaroo onwards (6 days later) i have had constant severe stomach pain. Ive been to the doctors twice, blood tests came up ok and have just had more testing to look for parasites. I havent got the results yet, but im 99% sure it is a parasite problem, and it all started a few hours after i ate the raw Kangaroo. I also hadnt eaten any suspect food at all in the 48 hours leading up to the Kangaroo meat, so i can easily say it wasnt anything else i had eaten.
Ill be happy to post back here when the test results arrive.
I always thought it was safe to eat reasonably raw, but my opinion has now changed. I wouldnt eat unless cooked all the way through from now onwards.

Comment: Sorry to hear you are nit well, but a few hours ir a really, really short time. Parasites usually don't develop this fast. Do you or your doctors suspect any particular paradite?

Comment: This line is particularly problematic "I also hadnt eaten any suspect food at all in the 48 hours leading up to the Kangaroo meat, so i can easily say it wasn't anything else" Almost *all* foodborne illnesses take longer than that to develop symptoms. Parasitic infections can take weeks or even months to show symptoms.