# Sashimi Recommendations?

Tags: fish, raw, wasabi, sashimi

I've recently been to China, and I've tasted an extraordinary dish I wasn't used to. Later, I've found out that the name is Sashimi, which is made with raw fish (salmon) and wasabi. Now I want to make it my self.

Can this be made at home? Is it difficult?

Comment: Tomas, I edited your question to remove your recipe request. Noted in our [FAQ](http://seasonedadvice.com/faq), recipe requests are not appropriate here. However, since sashimi doesn't really have much of a "recipe" to speak of, I simply edited instead of closing. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Sory I didn't read the FAQ!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Welcome to the site Tomas. [Sashimi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sashimi) is actually a Japanese delicacy. It's quite simple because it's just raw seafood, that has been sliced into bite-sized pieces. It is typically served with soy sauce and wasabi paste. Pickled ginger is also served as a palate cleanser between bites.

There really isn't a "recipe" to speak of, you simply buy *really* fresh "[sashimi grade](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/723/60)" fish.

If you are buying fish with the intention of eating it raw, there are a few things you should know:

- Don't buy from a supermarket
- Buy it from a fishmonger, preferably one you know and trust
- Make sure you let your fishmonger know that you intend to eat your purchase raw.
- Bring a little cooler with some ice to the store with you, take your fish home in this.

If you have concerns about the safety of eating raw fish, you can find more info in the answers to this question: [Is it safe to eat raw fish?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2923/60)

---

Cutting sashimi is rightfully considered an art. Sushi chefs in Japan go to school and apprentice under masters to learn all the intricacies involved. You can approximate in your home, and it will still taste great, but won't be as pretty.

---

Here are some common, and popular cuts you should try:

- Salmon (Sake)
- Squid  (Ika)
- Shrimp (Ebi)
- Bluefin Tuna (Maguro)
- Fatty Tuna (Toro)
- Yellowtail (Hamachi)
- Scallop (Hotate-gai) <sub>my favorite!</sub>

Comment: I think some supermarkets have their own fish mongers, what you really mean to say is don't buy fillets and use those for sashimi.