# Can I cook my tandoori chicken in the marinade for a sauce?

Tags: chicken, sauce, marinade

I'm cooking tandoori chicken and I was wondering if I can cook the chicken in the marinade to make a sauce.

Marinade:

- 300ml Greek yogurt
- Ginger
- Garlic
- Masala seasoning
- Turmeric
- Cumin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you reuse marinade used with raw chicken?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1297/can-you-reuse-marinade-used-with-raw-chicken)

Comment: @Luciano I don't see this as a duplicate. The OP is not asking about storing the marinade and using it at a later date.

Comment: @Cindy still there are answers there discussing fresh marinade as well

Comment: @Luciano It's still a different question.

Comment: If cooking made the chicken safe then it made the marinade safe.

Comment: All versions of tandoori chicken I've had have been served dry; any sauce should be on the side. So while cooking the chicken in the marinade/sauce may be safe, and may be nice, it wouldn't be tandoori chicken.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original question was edited ...

If the chicken is cooked with the marinade, then yes you  can use it as a sauce.

-----  old answer

Probably not.

You will need to cook down the yogurt based marinade to remove risk of contamination and I'm not certain how well the marinade will hold when cooked.

I'd try it.

If it fails, you could just make a fresh batch of "marinade" and use it as a sauce.

Comment: Hey Max, the question is the same before and after the edit, I just made the title more clear.